# shopping cart: delete doesn't work as supposed to

Tags: php

I'm having some problem with the "delete" of my shopping cart script (is a case of a switch)

```
case 'delete':
        if ($cart) {
            $items = explode(',',$cart);
            $newcart = '';
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                if ($_GET['id'] != $item) {
                    if ($newcart != '') {
                        $newcart .= ','.$item;
                    } else {
                        $newcart = $item;
                    }
                }
            }
            $cart = $newcart;
            $_SESSION['cart'] = $cart;
        }
        break;
```

Example: $_SESSION['cart'] = 1,2,1;
The problem is that when a client bought twice the same item, it deletes both. How can i fix it?

Comment: Can you clarify what *exactly* goes wrong where?

Comment: i put it down below: is when it deletes, it deletes all the items with the same id (if a client bought twice the same thing, it deletes twice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a flag, something like:

```
$items = explode(',',$cart);
        $newcart = '';
        $flag = false;
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($_GET['id'] == $item && $flag === false) { $flag = true; continue; }


                if ($newcart != '') {
                    $newcart .= ','.$item;
                } else {
                    $newcart = $item;
                }

        }
$cart = $newcart;
```

Answer (score 1):

This snipped could help:

```
$items = explode(',',$cart);
$newcart = array();
$deleted = false;
foreach ($items as $item) {
  if (!$deleted && $_GET['id'] == $item) {
    $deleted = true;
    continue;
  }
  $newcart[] = $item;
}
print_r(implode(',',$newcart));
```

Comment: YES! work like a charm. Thanks a lot, i see that constructing the new cart this way works better.